# Как отключить PHP директиву disable_functions в php.ini ?

Tags: php, ubuntu, php.ini, apache2.2

На официальном сайте написано, что её можно отключить только в самом конфигурационном файле `php.ini`. У меня `Ubuntu` с `Apache2` и `PHP` как модуль для `Apache`. Там этих `php.ini` целых 3 файла. Я во всех отключил эту директиву и после перезагрузки сервера она всё равно работает. Как это вообще возможно? Я там всё стёр в `php.ini`. Патом гляжу инфу через `phpinfo()`; и там целый список этих функций. Вообще не понимаю откуда он их берёт. Может эту директиву надо ещё где то отключать?

Все делал под рутом. Все изменения сохранились.

Comment: php_ini_set в .htaccess и в vhost ?

Comment: Выполните echo phpinfo(); посмотрите, по какому пути подгружается php.ini(в самом начале), это и есть файл, в котором нужно делать изменения. Если вы устанавливали PHP5, то файл конфигурации обычно лежит по такому пути: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Answer (score 1):

Проделывали? `sudo gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` должно помочь!

Суть в том что если редактировать php.ini не под root, изменения могут не сохраняться изза недостатка прав!